# Reduce database records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table:

```
GroupId StartDate           Time
1       2013-01-01 15:00    10
1       2013-01-01 16:00    10
1       2013-01-01 17:00    10
1       2013-01-02 08:00    10
1       2013-01-02 09:00    10
2       2013-01-01 15:00    2
2       2013-01-01 16:00    2
```

which has record for every hour in above example (in real data it is record for every minute).

I need to have such format for today and yesterday, but after some time it starts to be redundant - day grouping is more than enough.

I ways thinking about following way of reducing above records:

1. run procedure every day which will copy data to new "temp" table, grouping them together. Then drop original table and rename "temp" one. But of course I will have to restore all relations (GroupId column in above example).
2. have two tables all the time, and query View instead of the table (I only INSERT and SELECT records). Every day copy grouped records to "grouped" table and remove them from "detailed" table

In my opinion both options generate problems, but maybe there exist a better way?

**UPDATE**

Because of the first answer I think I might be misunderstood. The result records should be following

```
GroupId StartDate           Time
1       2013-01-01 00:00    30
1       2013-01-02 00:00    20
2       2013-01-01 00:00    4
```

So it is one record per day and group, and Time column is a sum for every detailed record.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating additional tables, you can just add an additional Rowid column to your table(auto generated id), and group by the unique columns, and use the following query:

```
DELETE Table1 
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT MIN(RowId) as RowId, GroupId, StartDate, Time 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY GroupId, StartDate, Time
) as Table2 ON
Table1.RowId = Table2.RowId
WHERE
Table2.RowId IS NULL
```

Here is my explanation:
I have the table with the following data:

```
 GroupId    StartDate    Time    Rowid
 1  2013-01-01 15:01:00.000 10  101
 1  2013-01-01 15:09:00.000 10  102
 1  2013-01-01 15:59:00.000 10  103
 1  2013-01-01 16:42:00.000 10  104
 1  2013-01-01 16:52:00.000 10  105
 1  2013-01-01 17:21:00.000 10  106
 1  2013-01-01 17:46:00.000 10  107
 1  2013-01-01 17:56:00.000 10  108
 1  2013-01-02 08:10:00.000 10  109
 1  2013-01-02 09:20:00.000 10  110
 2  2013-01-01 15:45:00.000 2   111
 2  2013-01-01 15:35:00.000 2   112
 2  2013-01-01 16:35:00.000 2   113
```

Now after I run the following query I will be left with only one row per day:

```
DELETE Table1 
FROM test24 Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT MIN(RowId) as RowId, GroupId, Convert(Varchar(10),StartDate,120)StartDate, Time 
FROM test24 
GROUP BY GroupId, Convert(Varchar(10),StartDate,120), Time
) as Table2 ON
Table1.RowId = Table2.RowId
WHERE
Table2.RowId IS NULL

 GroupId    StartDate           Time    rowid
   1    2013-01-01 15:01:00.000 10  101
   1    2013-01-02 08:10:00.000 10  109
   2    2013-01-01 15:45:00.000 2   111
```

Now, you can run the update statement to change the date as per your required format.

```
Update test24
set StartDate=Convert(Varchar(10),StartDate,120)

GroupId StartDate     Time    rowid
   1    2013-01-01       10   101
   1    2013-01-02       10   109
   2    2013-01-01        2   111
```

Comment: If RowId is autogenerated how it can be NULL?

Comment: @Garath this delete query is intended to remove duplicates. It has no bearing on your situation unless you first update row having min(id) with summary data.

Comment: Lets say you have 4 rows with the identical data, and there row ids are 101, 102, 103 and 104, now in the above mentioned inner query the minimum Rowid would be 101 and when you will do the left outer join with the outer, rest of the 3 rows will have rowid as Null(Table1.RowId = Table2.RowId)

Comment: @Sonam but your query lost time information, because you did not sum it up

Answer (score 0):

You can have a history table and a current table.

You have to have a process that reads and consolidates current rows and creates history rows.

You don't have to run the process daily.  You could run the process monthly on the rows from two months prior.  In other words, on the first Saturday in August, you create the history rows for June.  Your current table would have between one month and two months of rows.

You would probably want to create a view and / or stored processes that would select from the current table first, then the history table, so that most of your other applications wouldn't have to know to process two tables.

Comment: @Garath: Yes, it is your second idea.